# Is it possible to represent 'average value' in programming?

Tags: math, average

Had a tough time thinking of an appropriate title, but I'm just trying to code something that can auto compute the following simple math problem:

> The average value of a,b,c is 25. The average value of b,c is 23. What is the value of 'a'?

For us humans we can easily compute that the value of 'a' is 29, without the need to know b and c. But I'm not sure if this is possible in programming, where we code a function that takes in the average values of 'a,b,c' and 'b,c' and outputs 'a' automatically.

Comment: It could be done, you just need to step back and think a bit about what exactly you're trying to solve and write code to solve that problem. What is the problem that you're trying to solve? You also want to consider that if you have an average value of some collection of numbers and want to know what to add to that collection to obtain a different average value, what number you add is entirely dependent on how many values are in the collection. In your example, if the average of b, d, and d is 23, having a as 29 would result in an average of 24.5, not 25.

Comment: Well, you can easily replace the average by a sum. Thus `b + c = 46` and `a + b + c = 75`. Then you take the difference `(a + b + c) - (b + c) = (75 - 46). By simplifying, you have `a = 75 -46 = 29`. For code, the solution would really depends on the range of problem you need to solve. At some point, you would essentially represent your equation by matrix and then do some operation to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do this. The reason for this is that you can model the sort of problem being described here as a system of linear equations. For example, when you say that the average of a, b, and c is 25, then you're saying that

> a / 3 + b / 3 + c / 3 = 25.

Adding in the constraint that the average of b and c is 23 gives the equation

> b / 2 + c / 2 = 23.

More generally, any constraint of the form "the average of the variables x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub> is M" can be written as

> x<sub>1</sub> / n + x<sub>2</sub> / n + ... + x<sub>n</sub> / n = M.

Once you have all of these constraints written out, solving for the value of a particular variable - or determining that many solutions exists - reduces to solving a system of linear equations. There are a number of techniques to do this, with Gaussian elimination with backpropagation being a particularly common way to do this (though often you'd just hand this to MATLAB or a linear algebra package and have it do the work for you.)

There's no guarantee in general that given a collection of equations the computer can determine whether or not they have a solution or to deduce a value of a variable, but this happens to be one of the nice cases where the shape of the contraints make the problem amenable to exact solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I have figured some things out. To answer the question as per title directly, it's possible to represent average value in programming. 1 possible way is to create a list of map data structures which store the set collection as `key` (eg. "a,b,c"), while the average value of the set will be the `value` (eg. 25).

Extract the key and split its string by comma, store into list, then multiply the average value by the size of list to get the total (eg. 25x3 and 23x2). With this, no semantic information will be lost.

As for the context to which I asked this question, the more proper description to the problem is "Given a set of average values of different combinations of variables, is it possible to find the value of each variable?" The answer to this is open. I can't figure it out, but below is an attempt in describing the logic flow if one were to code it out:

Match the lists (from Paragraph 2) against one another in all possible combinations to check if a list contains all elements in another list. If so, substract the lists (eg. abc-bc) as well as the value (eg. 75-46). If upon substracting we only have 1 variable in the collection, then we have found the value for this variable.

If there's still more than 1 variables left such as abcd - bc = ad, then store the values as a map data structure and repeat the process, till the point where the substraction count in the full iteration is 0 for all possible combinations (eg. ac can't substract bc). This is unfortunately **not** where it ends.

Further solutions may be found by combining the lists (eg. ac + bd = abcd) to get more possible ways to subtract and derive at the answer. When this is the case, you just don't know when to stop trying, and the list of combinations will get exponential. Maybe someone with strong related mathematical theories may be able to prove that upon a certain number of iteration, further additions are useless and hence should stop. Heck, it may even be possible that negative values are also helpful, and hence contradict what I said earlier about 'ac' can't subtract 'bd' (to get a,c,-b,-d). This will give even more combinations to compute.

People with stronger computing science foundations may try what templatetypedef has suggested.